# How to use android button png as a button in my app

Tags: java, android, button

I have a two png files. The button and it's "pressed state".

1)How do I replace the default android button with my png(the text of the button is included in the png, there's no need to define a textView over the image.

2) And also how do I implement the "onPress" state png???.

I've been 3 days searching for answers but there's little to no information on this subject in particular. I just found the rotate animations an all of that, but nothing on how to replace a default button with a drawable and then use another png file when the user press the button

Comment: 1) `android:background` 2) `android:background` using a `StateListDrawable`

Comment: `I've been 3 days searching for answers but there's little to no information on this subject in particular.` : have you find `selector` drawable ? you can do same by creating selector with normal and pressed state. see following example [Android Button Selector tutorial with example](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/03/android-button-selector-tutorial-with.html)

Comment: Where did you search? on The Mickey Mouse Adventures? I found the duplicate post in no time...

Comment: sorry Frank. You found it quickly cause you knew what to look. I'm a noob at this, sometimes is harder to know what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers, I could implement the selector correctly xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an image in your `Button` you just have to put it on the `drawable` folder and then in the background of your `Button` you can do:

```
android:background="@drawable/image"
```

Comment: thanks my friend, I was able to implement it properly xD